# Ignore original Model declaration when using Partial View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Each of my views require a navbar which is laid out in a partial view called _NavigationPartial. This partial view uses

```
@model IEnumerable<ProOptInteractive.Models.ProductCategory>
```

and it is required for this navbar to function. However, in some of my views, i have declared other models, which overwrite the model in the partial view and it gives me an error when attempting to open those views in the browser:

```
@model ProOptInteractive.Models.ProductCategory <!-- this is incompatible! -->

@Html.Partial("_NavigationPartial")
```

How can I set the partial view to ignore the original model declaration in my views?

Comment: this is confusing b/c partials are not bound to parent's model

Comment: This is the error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ProOptInteractive.Models.ProductCategory', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ProOptInteractive.Models.ProductCategory]'. Apparently they are bound :P

Comment: Very odd. I know they're not because I use partials daily. Clearly more info is needed, but I'm not sure what...

Answer (score 0):

you should use the overload that allows you to pass a model to it. If i'm not mistaken Html.Partial will pass the parent's model to the partial view. If you do `@Html.Partial("_NavigationPartial", new[]{Model})` that should satisfy your partial's requirement for an IEnumerable model.

You cannot make a view forget it's model type, the only thing you can do is to make sure you pass the correct model type to it.